# magento: setup on xampp in windows

Tags: mysql, magento

Please help:
I am having problem setting up magento on locathost and facing this error.

any help is appreciated.

below is the error message:-

```
a:5:{i:0;s:172:"Error in file: 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\sql\sales_setup\mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-
0.9.17.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: sales/quote_shipping_rate";i:1;s:960:"

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.9.16', '1.6.0.8')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.9.16', '1.6.0.8')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: First hit in Google - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/246668/

Comment: It really should be a requirement that people [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking questions. I doubt meta would be receptive to the idea though...